# How can I reset libcec / HDMI settings on raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, reset, monitor, hdmi

Recently I was experimenting with controlling my Raspberry Pi's HDMI screen using libcec. I made a few settings changes (which regrettably I didn't keep track of), and when I re-booted the Pi, I got a blank screen.

This now happens every time I boot the Pi normally. I see a few boot messages and then the screen abruptly goes black (before I'm given the option of logging in). The only way I can access the command line is if I add "init=/bin/sh" to cmdline.txt.

What I'd like to do is undo the changes and return the Pi's HDMI settings back to normal. Is there a simple way to do a total reset of libcec / cec-client? Do I need to uninstall libcec? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: It occurs to me that the problem may be the Pi is trying to send data to the wrong target, either over VGA or to some virtual "other screen" (note: I only have monitor actually connected to the Pi). I don't know if that helps at all.